# list.extend and list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

When I need to add several identical items to the list I use list.extend:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
a.extend(['d']*3)
```

Result

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd']
```

But, how to do the similar with list comprehension?

```
a = [['a',2], ['b',2], ['c',1]]
[[x[0]]*x[1] for x in a]
```

Result

```
[['a', 'a'], ['b', 'b'], ['c']]
```

But I need this one

```
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Stacked LCs.

```
[y for x in a for y in [x[0]] * x[1]]
```

Comment: Thanks! It works but I don't even understand how to read this expression.

Comment: `for x in a` extracts each of the elements of `a` one at a time into `x`. `for y in ...` creates a new list from `x` and extracts its elements one at a time into `y`. It all happens at the same time (more or less), causing it all to be at the same nesting level.

Comment: It is usually clearer with unpacking: [y for (item, times) in a for y in [item] * times]

Comment: @tokland: +1 that's what I'd have done. But I'd avoid using `times` because it looks too much like a typo of `items`. Use for example `repeat` instead.

Comment: If think this is also called [nested list comprehension](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nested-list-comprehensions-in-python/):  ```flatten_matrix = [val for sublist in matrix for val in sublist] ```

Answer (score 16):

An [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) approach:

```
import itertools

def flatten(it):
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(it)

pairs = [['a',2], ['b',2], ['c',1]]
flatten(itertools.repeat(item, times) for (item, times) in pairs)
# ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> a = [['a',2], ['b',2], ['c',1]]
>>> [i for i, n in a for k in range(n)]
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer extend over list comprehensions:

```
a = []
for x, y in l:
    a.extend([x]*y)
```

Comment: I think he's asking how to do extend from *within* a list comprehension, but I think a simple loop like this is more readable if performance isn't a concern.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a = [['a',2], ['b',2], ['c',1]]
>>> sum([[item]*count for item,count in a],[])
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import operator
a = [['a',2], ['b',2], ['c',1]]
nums = [[x[0]]*x[1] for x in a]
nums = reduce(operator.add, nums)
```

Comment: `reduce(operator.add, ...)` is O(n^2).