# How to extend within list comprehensions

Tags: python

Still trying to wrap my head around list comprehensions. Below, 'e' is a list. How would I write this as a list comprehension?

```
events = []
        for req in request:
            e = req[attr]
            events.extend(e)
```

I tried the following and it gave me a list of lists([[a,b],[c,d]] rather than a flat list [a, b, c, d]

```
events = [req[attr] for req in request]
```

Comment: ```events = [val for req in request for val in req[attr]]```?

Comment: this is definitely a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/3899658/14385360

Comment: Does this answer your question? [list.extend and list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899645/list-extend-and-list-comprehension)

Comment: You said you want a "flat list"; searching for `list comprehension flatten` [gives you multiple good answers right off the top, without even mentioning Python](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=list+comprehension+flat).

Comment: Please also specifcially see https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two generators in the list comprehension:

```
events = [val for req in request for val in req[attr]]
```

Comment: This works by breaking apart the list into elements and then place each element into the list?

Comment: Yes. It is a shorter form of nested loops and loops over every item of every sublist